# get django ajax request.POST and utf-8 problem

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, utf-8

1.
I had to send request.POST a dict of dict,

```
big_dict = {k:{kk:vv, kk1: vv1}, k1:{kk:vv, kk1: vv1}}
```

and ajax always somehow made it into one dict like

```
one_dict = {k[kk]:vv, k[kk1]:vv1, k1[kk]:vv, k1[kk1]:vv1}
```

someone told me to

```
JSON.stringify(big_dict)
```

before ajax request and then json.loads it in my python django views.

```
json.loads(request.POST.get('data'))
```

it worked all damn fine till someone uploaded a chinese character named file.

At the third step of `json.loads` in my view,

**(wrong)**
the key and value of my big_dict is still good, looking fine, displaying proper chinese character.

**(edited)**
the key and value of my big_dict, chinese characters in one value looks good, and not in the other.

```
{'0': {'designer': 'EV', 'number': '0229', 'version': '', 'bracket': '(120门幅)', 'imgUrl': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/temp/EV-0229(120%E9%97%A8%E5%B9%85%EF%BC%89.jpg'}}
```

but when I try to

```
for k, v in big_dict.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        # do something with kk and vv
```

chinese characters within vv becomes all wrong.
and os is telling me no such file.

It looked like a simple problem, I searched a web for over an hour and tried things, nothing worked..

Thanks anyone in advance for helping me out.

**EDIT**

**script from template**

```
$('.designInfoSave').click(function() {
    let num = $('.designBox').length;
    let bcontext = {};
    for (let i = 0; i<num; i++) {
        let infoBox = $('#'+i+"-infoBox");
        let image = $('#image'+i);
        image.toArray();
        let children = infoBox.children();
        children.toArray();
        bcontext[i] = {
            'designer': children[2].value,
            'number': children[4].value,
            'version': children[6].value,
            'bracket': children[8].value,
            'imgUrl': image[0].currentSrc,
        };
    }
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'update_des_info' %}",
            data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'context':JSON.stringify(bcontext)},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                $("#album").hide();
                $(".ajaxResult").show();
            }
        }
    )
});
```

**views.py**

```
import json
import os.path


def update_des_info(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return
    queryset = json.loads(request.POST.get('context'))
    print(queryset)
    exist = 0
    created = 0

    for k, v in queryset.items():
        designer = v['designer']
        number = v['number']
        version = v['version']
        bracket = v['bracket']
        fp = v['imgUrl'][v['imgUrl'].rfind('/media/')+6:]
        n, c = Design.objects.get_or_create(designer=designer, number=number, version=version)
        if c is True:
            created += 1
        else:
            exist += 1
        if n.bracket != bracket:
            n.bracket = bracket
        fpp = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + fp
        p, fn = os.path.split(fpp)
        nfp = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'designs', 'image', fn)
        shutil.move(fpp, nfp)
        if not n.image:
            n.image = nfp
        n.save()
```

Comment: Can you share your AJAX call, or the clientside method of where you are sending the data?

Comment: @coler-j yeah! I did! Thanks!